# How to disable the scrolling of gridview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an android app in which I have to add a background image to gridview and the background should scroll with the grid view.

My problem is that I have added the background image with the gridView but the background is not scrolling with the grid view.

I followed http://www.firstdroid.com/2011/02/06/android-tutorial-gridview-with-icon-and-text/.
But that didnt help for this purpose.

Any idea or help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a url above, from where I took help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building an android app in which I have to add a background image to gridview and the background should scroll with the grid view.

AFAIK, this is not possible with `GridView`. Most likely, you will have to create your own `AdapterView` implementation with your desired behavior.